# Program not comparing JFrame textfield value with number generated in other class

Tags: java, jframe

I made a little random math generator, which gives out 2 random numbers and a random operator but when I call my check result method in my ok button, I always get the "Errado" ("Wrong") string which means it's not properly comparing the value of the textfield with the result of whatever math problem was presented. Leaving relevent code from both classes down here with comments on where I'm having issues and 2 for ease of understanding. Help's appreciated!

```
public class geraAritmetica {
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList();
    int a;
    char ops = '?';
    int max = 10;
    int min = 1;
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int res;

    Random r = new Random();
    
    public int gerarNums(){
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            a = (int) (Math.random()*range) + min;
            nums.add(a);
        }
        return a;
    }
    
    public char gerarOps(){
        switch(r.nextInt(4)){
            case 1 : ops = '+';
                     res = nums.get(0) + nums.get(1);
            break;
            case 2: ops = '-';
                    res = nums.get(0) - nums.get(1);
                    break;
            case 3: ops = '*';
                    res = nums.get(0) * nums.get(1);
                    break;
            case 4: ops = '/';
                    res = nums.get(0) / nums.get(1);
                    break;    
            
            default: ops = '+';
                     res = nums.get(0) + nums.get(1);
            break;
        }
        return ops;
    }
        
        public boolean checkRes(){   //everytime I call this method always get the same string "Errado" ("Wrong") in the label.          
            if(Integer.parseInt(FrameEnsinoAritmetica.jTextField1.getText()) == res){
                FrameEnsinoAritmetica.jLabel2.setText("Correto!");
                return true;
            }
            else FrameEnsinoAritmetica.jLabel2.setText("Errado!");
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```

```
public class FrameEnsinoAritmetica extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   geraAritmetica a = new geraAritmetica(); //creating object of class at the start of my JFrame class
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  //generating numbers and operator (it prints fine in another label)                                       

        int b = a.gerarNums();
        int c = a.gerarNums();
        char s = a.gerarOps();
        
        jLabel1.setText(b + " " +s+ " " + c);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                            
        a.checkRes(); //everytime I call this method always get the same string "Errado" ("Wrong") in the label.          
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be referencing to the `FrameEnsinoAritmetica` class directly not the actual instance of your FrameEnsinoAritmetica jFrame that you see on screen. For example, using this in another class will not reference to the frame that you see on screen:

```
String text = FrameEnsinoAritmetica.jTextField1.getText();
```

But using this would work:

```
String text = yourInstanceOfEnsinoAritmetica.jTextField1.getText();
```

To fix this we could pass the current instance of the `FrameEnsinoAritmetica` that is shown on screen into the `checkRes` method, which we do by modifying `checkRes` like so, and inside the method we replace `FrameEnsinoAritmetica` with `frame` to refer to the current instance:

```
    public boolean checkRes(FrameEnsinoAritmetica frame){   //everytime I call this method always get the same string "Errado" ("Wrong") in the label.          
        if(Integer.parseInt(frame.jTextField1.getText()) == res){
            frame.jLabel2.setText("Correto!");
            return true;
        }
        else frame.jLabel2.setText("Errado!");
        return false;
    }
```

Then we just update the `jButton1ActionPerformed` method to pass `this` which is the current instance of `FrameEnsinoAritmetica` into the updated `checkRes` method:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                            
    a.checkRes(this); //everytime I call this method always get the same string "Errado" ("Wrong") in the label.          
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure it wasn't working because of that but there's something else wrong. I made res a static int and decided to add it to the label to check if things worked but res isn't actually correct. I think it's just a random number and I can't understand why. Fe: 3+10=7, 2-7=1, etc...

Comment: For some reason the values being stored in the ArrayList aren't actually the values generated, I just created to variables to add to the label nums.get(0) nums.get(1) and they are both continuosly the same value which is 2.

Comment: Fixed it by getting values directly from instance of Frame, still unsure why values from ArrayList were coming out wrong but at least it's fixed, added as second answer. Thanks for the help btw!

Answer (score 0):

Fix part 2 (for res not being calculated properly)

```
public class FrameEnsinoAritmetica extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   geraAritmetica a = new geraAritmetica();
   public static int b;
   public static int c;
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        b = a.gerarNums();
        c = a.gerarNums();
        char s = a.gerarOps(this);
        
        jLabel1.setText(b + " " +s+ " " + c + " ");
    }
```

```
public class geraAritmetica {
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList();
    int a;
    char ops = '?';
    int max = 10;
    int min = 1;
    int range = max - min + 1;
    public static int res;

    Random r = new Random();

    public int gerarNums(){
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            a = (int) (Math.random()*range) + min;
            nums.add(a);
        }
        return a;
    }

    public char gerarOps(FrameEnsinoAritmetica frame){
        switch(r.nextInt(4)){
            case 1 : ops = '+';
                     res = frame.b + frame.c; //checking both variables directly from JFrame class instead of getting through index from ArrayList.
                    break;
            case 2: ops = '-';
                    res = res = frame.b - frame.c;
                    break;
            case 3: ops = '*';
                    res = frame.b * frame.c;
                    break;
            case 4: ops = '/';
                    res = frame.b / frame.c;
                    break;    
            
            default: ops = '+';
                     res = frame.b + frame.c;
            break;
        }
        return ops;
    }
        
        public boolean checkRes(FrameEnsinoAritmetica frame){
            if(Integer.parseInt(frame.jTextField1.getText()) == res){
                frame.jLabel2.setText("Correto!");
                return true;
            }
            else frame.jLabel2.setText("Errado!");
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```